# React Redux - Dispatch action in useEffect only if the previous route is same as new route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm making a social media app and I have a state for `newsfeed` stored in redux which I want to preserve even when route changes.

**The Problem**
I want only to run the dispatch inside the useEffect hook only if I change route but the route is same as before eg: Clicking the Nav logo which redirects to newsfeed `/`. If I'm in `NewsFeed` where path = `/` and click the logo - it will fire again. But If I were in different route say `Profile` `/profile` then go to newsfeed again - it won't fire.

**newsFeedReducer.js**

```
const initState = {
  items: [],
  offset: 0
}

export default (state = initState, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
      case GET_FEED_SUCCESS:
         return {
            items: [...state, ...action.payload],
            offset: state.offset + 1
         }
         ...
  }
}
```

**NewsFeed.jsx**

```
const NewsFeed = () => {
   const newsFeed = useSelector(state => state.newsFeed);
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   useEffect(() => {
     // this works. However, this wont fire again when newsfeed unmounted since newsFeed
     // already has items.
     if (newsFeed.items.length === 0) { // this prevents dispatch from firing if newsfeed is empty.
        dispatch(getNewsFeedStart({ offset: 0 })); 
     }
  
     // If I removed the condition, it will always fetch for new feed everytime it mounts
     // which is not what I want. I want it to fetch only if I switched route but 
     // previous route is same as current  
   }, []);
};

export default NewsFeed;
```

What is a better workaround to prevent the dispatch from firing if the `NewsFeed` unmounts but the the route being changed is same as previous? eg: Clicking the nav logo

I want to include it my condition so that this wont fire whenever changed route except `/`

It will be like:

```
  if (newsFeed.items.length === 0 || ???? ) { // How??
     dispatch(getNewsFeedStart({ offset: 0 })); 
  }
```

I'm thinking that I should just add dispatch to the Nav logo but it seems that it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it.

My first option was to add the dispatch method to the Navbar Logo but this was kinda anti-pattern.

So my solution was to pass state to the route in my NavBar logo

```
const NavBar = (props) => {
   const { pathname } = useLocation();
  
   return (
     <NavLink to={{
        pathname: '/',
        state: { from: pathname }
     }}
     >
         My Logo
     </NavLink>
     ...  
   )
}
```

Now I have access to previous pathname to check for

```
const Home = (props) => {
  const from = props.location.state?.from || null;

  useEffect(() => {
     if (newsFeed.items.length === 0 || from === '/') { // wont fire to any other routes
       dispatch(getNewsFeedStart({ offset: 0 }));
    }

  }, [])
}
```

Now dispatch will only fire if previous pathname equal to Home route;